# WSUS server for offline network

Tags: offline, windows-update

First post on this forum,

I work on an offline network with a lot of computers on an active directory. I would like to automatically update Windows on all of them. I found WSUS offline but it only works on a single computer. I also found WSUS Server but from what I understood, it needs to be connected to another WSUS machine with Internet (which is not possible for me).

What I wish to do is a mix between them: being able to download updates on a computer, transfer them manually to a WSUS Server, and change the windows update source through GPO to my WSUS Server.

I've found other software like batchpatch or autopatcher but none of them could do that.

Does anyone know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure a WSUS server to operate offline, check the MS documentation regarding this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/security-updates/windowsupdateservices/18127442

Hope this help

Comment: It seems to be what I want yes, I don't know why I didn't find this before. Thanks !